# Kubernetes java-api update container image

Tags: java, api, client, kubernetes, fabric8

I'm trying to automate deployment of test builds in CI with Gradle and the Fabric8 Java kubernetes-client.

I'm trying to find the right syntax to update the RC with the new Docker image tag (not :latest).

Something like...

```
client.replacationControllers()
      .inNamespace('default')
      .withName('mycirc')
      .edit()
      .editSpec()
      .editTemplate()
        .editSpec()
          .withContainer('mycontainername')
            .withImage('myimage:newtag')
          .endContainer()   // <--- Not sure how to do this previous line
        .endSpec()
      .endTemplate()
      .endSpec()
      .done()
```

Can we update containers without having to totally delete and rebuild it?

Comment: You can update the image in the RC (just try `kubectl edit rc <name>`), it will not take effect unless you kill all containers though. A rolling-update will slowly roll out the new image. I don't know enough about Gradle to comment, so I'm giving you the Kubernetes answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of updating an image here:
https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/FullExample.java#L136

```
            // Update the RC - change the image to apache
            client.replicationControllers().inNamespace("thisisatest").withName("nginx-controller").edit().editSpec().editTemplate().withNewSpec()
                    .addNewContainer().withName("nginx").withImage("httpd")
                    .addNewPort().withContainerPort(80).endPort()
                    .endContainer()
                    .endSpec()
                    .endTemplate()
                    .endSpec().done();
```

Though as was pointed out in the comments, this probably doesn't update the pods immediately, unless the client is doing it.

It looks like the client supports rolling update, as well, which will update the pods:
                client.replicationControllers().inNamespace("thisisatest").withName("nginx-controller").rolling().updateImage("nginx");

Answer (score 0):

You can also do rolling-update on replica-set by following code

```html
    private static void updateRc(KubernetesClient client){
        System.out.println("updating rollinh");
       // client.replicationControllers().inNamespace("default").withName("my-nginx").rolling().updateImage("nginx:latest");
        client.extensions().replicaSets().inNamespace("default").withName("fgrg-73-nginxcontainer1-74-97775d4d8").rolling().updateImage("nginx:latest");
        System.out.println("done");
    }
```

Comment: One way to do rolling update via api is to first check if deployment.spec.updateStrategy is RollingUpdate and if not then update it after this just edit the deployment with the new image tag.